# Validate when passing individual data using JSON.stringify

Tags: laravel

Before passing the data to Controller, the data is being added :

```
formData.push({"name":"channels","value":JSON.stringify(channels)});
```

Cause of this even when no data is present, its passed like 
    'channels' => '[]'

Now the issue is when I try to validate this in validator, I cannot use 
     'channels'      =>'required',
     'channels.*'    =>'required|exists:channels,id',

How do validate the above data? Don't want to convert the format as its a working system. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Updated for Request All Params:
    `'_token' => 'DjqgmNab0o3ifrVrSvHh6dM5vxLP7tZDc47pq05r',
    'startdate' => '05 Sep 2018',
    'years' => NULL,
    'months' => NULL,
    'enddate' => NULL,
    'addChannel' => NULL,
    'offerRuns' => 'UL',
    'numberOfRuns' => NULL,
    'limitPeriod' => 'FP',
    'licenseAudioTrack' => '1',
    'amount' => NULL,
    'include_materials_costs' => '1',
    'include_withholding_taxes' => '1',
    'paymentTermsType' => 'US',
    'termsAndConditionDescription' => NULL,
    'document_s3_url' => NULL,
    'file' => NULL,
    'fileSize' => NULL,
    'materialSpecificationDescription' => NULL,
    'note' => NULL,
    'countries' => '[]',
    'platforms' => '["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]',
    'platforms-exclusive' => '[]',
    'platforms-non-exclusive' => '[]',
    'platforms-holdback' => '[]',
    'channels' => '[]',
    'languages' => '[["56","AL",1,"seller"]]',
    'currencySelectedTerm' => 'EP',
    'currencyId' => '1',
    'paymentTerms' => '[]'`

Comment: print output of dd($request()->all());

Comment: print output of dd(\Request::all()) and paste here.

Comment: have you used `min:1` as the size in your `channels` rule? to ensure the minimum length of the 'array' is 1

Comment: adding min also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the present validation rule. It states:

> **present**
>
> The field under validation must be present in the input data but can
>   be empty.

Also look into sometimes rule:

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a
>   field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly
>   accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: They are compulsory fields and I want them to select the valid channels, countries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood `channels` is passed as JSON string & `required` validator is not working because it is not an empty string.

You can create a custom validator to validate empty JSON string & use it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class JsonRequired implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return ! empty(json_decode($value, true));
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute is required.';
    }
}
```

And use it as `'channels' =>'new JsonRequired'`.

If you only need once throughout your application, you may use a Closure instead of a rule object.

[Laravel custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode for data first and then apply validations

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request_data = $request->all();

    foreach($request_data as $key=>$value)
    {
        $request_data[$key] = json_decode($value);
    }

    // And then pass data in validator rules

    $rules = [
       // All rules here
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request_data, $rules);
    // other code
}
```